# How to find a position vector given several other position vectors with a given relationship?

Tags: vectors

This is a question with regards to position vectors:

> Relative to the origin $O$, the position vector of $A$ is $6i+6j$ and the position vector of $B$ is $12i-2j$. The point $C$ lies on $\overrightarrow {AB}$ such that $\overrightarrow {AC}=\frac {3}{4}\overrightarrow {AB}$. Find the position vector of $C$.

As of now, I have found $\overrightarrow {AB}$ and $\overrightarrow {AC}$:

$\overrightarrow {AB} = \overrightarrow {OB}-\overrightarrow {OA}$
$\overrightarrow {AB} = 12i-2j-(6i+6j)$
$\overrightarrow {AB} = 12i-2j-6i-6j$
$\therefore \overrightarrow {AB} = 6i-8j$

$\overrightarrow {AC} = \frac {3}{4}\overrightarrow {AB}$
$\overrightarrow {AC} = \frac {3}{4}\cdot (6i-8j)$
$\overrightarrow {AC} = \frac {3}{4}\cdot 2(3i-4j)$
$\overrightarrow {AC} = \frac {3}{2}\cdot (3i-4j)$
$\overrightarrow {AC} = \frac {3(3i-4j)}{2}$
$\therefore \overrightarrow {AC} = \frac {9i-12j}{2}$

How would $\overrightarrow {OC}$ be found?

Looking forward to a response! Also, I'm still new to MSE, so I would really appreciate any and all feedback. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? Where have you encountered a problem? Add this to your question or it will be downvoted and closed.

Comment: You are new to MSE, so let me tell you that this is not an online calculator; you have to show your efforts to solve the problem, otherwise as @ShubhamJohri said, it will downvotes and eventually closed.

Comment: Anyways, if you show your efforts, then many are here to solve the problem, I promise, if you will, I will upvote it :)

Comment: @ultralegend5385 My sincere apologies. I was not aware of this. I have added some of my efforts to the question. I hope it helps. Thank you very much for helping me out!

Comment: @ShubhamJohri My sincere apologies. I have edited the question accordingly to clarify where the problem lies. Thank you very much for the feedback.

Comment: See! You showed your efforts and the other person answered! :)

Comment: @ultralegend5385 Yes, I understand now. Thank you very much! And thank you to @ShubhamJohri!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know $\vec{AB}=\vec{OB}-\vec{OA}$.

Similarly $\vec{AC}=\vec{OC}-\vec{OA}\implies\vec{OC}=\vec{OA}+\vec{AC}=(6\hat i+6\hat j)+(4.5\hat i-6\hat j)=10.5\hat i$.